# ETAGS with dependencies

Tags: c, etags

I'm trying to use emacs for C development.  From [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Create-Tags-Table.html), I understand that in order to see the definitions of functions, I need to use something called etags.  My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int i = 0;
  printf("i = ", i);

  return 0;
};
```

When I try to `M-.` the definition of `printf`, I see:

`No definitions found for: printf`

So, I try making an ETAGS file, with:

`M-! RET etags main.c RET`

And I see I now have a file in the directory called TAGS.  However, this didn't change anything.  When I `M-.` the function, I still see no definitions for it.

I can confirm that it works internally. That is, if I change my file to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int zero() {
  return 0;
};

int main()
{

  int i = 0;
  printf("i = ", i);

  i = zero();


  return 0;
};
```

And place my cursor on the line that calls `zero()`, and then `M-.` it takes me to the internal definition of `zero()`.

My question is:

### What do I need to do to see the definitions of dependencies?

Comment: What do you expect to see? The `printf` function is in a library that contains a bunch of compiled binaries. There is generally no source code available on a system. You *can* install the source code (at least on a Linux system) and then produce an etags file that contains those definitions, but the onus is on you: you'll have to find what library the function is part of, find where the source code for that library is, download it, keep it updated when new versions come out etc.

Comment: To see the definitions of dependencies, you need to run etags on the dependencies themselves: run etags in /usr/include. You can either combine those tags into the same file as your own code, or Emacs can load multiple tags files. The latter is what I do; set tags-table-list to the list of generated tags. I also recommend [ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags)